# Amplify - How to setup congnito to use email as username?

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify

Using AWS Amplify to create an authentication (Cognito) with Reactjs, the default username is a UUID. So when I log in to the system I see:

Hello f725e4a2-1f24-487d-9265-864947f5c5eb

How do I change this behavior? There may be a way of changing this in the frontend, but I would like to change this in the backend, because the list of users in Cognito has UUIDs as the identifier as well. I would like to see email as username instead.

Thank you!

Comment: you want to change the username value from being a UUID to been an email? i

Comment: Yes! Thats it my friend!

Answer (score 3):

You will have to create a new userpool because you cant update such a setting after a pool has been created.

Go to the console and configure a new user pool directly on the web it will provide you with login with email option

[image: congnito]

And then update to your Auth config with the new userpool details.

Example from [aws-amplify](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication)

```
import Amplify, { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {

        // REQUIRED only for Federated Authentication - Amazon Cognito Identity Pool ID
        identityPoolId: 'XX-XXXX-X:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-1234-abcd-1234567890ab',

        // REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Region
        region: 'XX-XXXX-X',

        // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito Federated Identity Pool Region 
        // Required only if it's different from Amazon Cognito Region
        identityPoolRegion: 'XX-XXXX-X',

        // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito User Pool ID
        userPoolId: 'XX-XXXX-X_abcd1234',

        // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito Web Client ID (26-char alphanumeric string)
        userPoolWebClientId: 'a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9j0k1l2m3',

        // OPTIONAL - Enforce user authentication prior to accessing AWS resources or not
        mandatorySignIn: false,

        // OPTIONAL - Configuration for cookie storage
        // Note: if the secure flag is set to true, then the cookie transmission requires a secure protocol
        cookieStorage: {
        // REQUIRED - Cookie domain (only required if cookieStorage is provided)
            domain: '.yourdomain.com',
        // OPTIONAL - Cookie path
            path: '/',
        // OPTIONAL - Cookie expiration in days
            expires: 365,
        // OPTIONAL - Cookie secure flag
        // Either true or false, indicating if the cookie transmission requires a secure protocol (https).
            secure: true
        },

        // OPTIONAL - customized storage object
        storage: new MyStorage(),

        // OPTIONAL - Manually set the authentication flow type. Default is 'USER_SRP_AUTH'
        authenticationFlowType: 'USER_PASSWORD_AUTH'
    }
});

// You can get the current config object
const currentConfig = Auth.configure();
```

Or update the `aws-exports.js` file directly with the new pool details.

If your application is already live you might need to migrate your users.

[How do I change the attributes of an Amazon Cognito user pool after creation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cognito-change-user-pool-attributes/) will be a good guide

Answer (score 1):

There is currently **no way** to update it after creating a user pool.

In the amplify folder, you will see a folder awscloudformation, and this contains a file "nested-cloudformation-stack.yml"

search for this "usernameAttributes" in the file and replace it with email rather then username

```
"usernameAttributes": "email",
```

Also, you can only set it before creating a cognito pool